# how to get String from getMetadata and not Future<String>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to get the Custom Metadata from a pdf I uploaded to Firebase but I keep getting

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

This is the widget in question-

```
futureFiles = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/files').listAll();
```

```
FutureBuilder<ListResult>(
  future: futureFiles,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final files = snapshot.data!.items;
      return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final file = files[index];
          return ListTile(
            leading:IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.download_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {}
                  ),
            title: Text(
              file.name,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
            ),
            subtitle: const Text(
              file.getMetadata().then((owner) => owner.customMetadata.toString(), //I tried this but I get //Future<String>
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              hoverColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.check_sharp,
                color: Colors.black38,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (_, index) =>
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
        itemCount: files.length,
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Something went wrong',
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  },
),
```

I tried using a future builder but that couldn't work since `getMetadata` is a method that only a Reference file can use.

Comment: There are multiple variables/fields/functions here that determine what happens and from which we can't see how they're initialized. Please edit your question to show a [minimal **self-contained, standalone** repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful), which should declare everything it uses, such as `downloadFile`, `isDownloading`, and any other things the code depends on.

Comment: I just edited the code with more information

Comment: "I tried using a future builder but that couldn't work" Please show the code where you tried that, because right now this looks like the same problem as everyone with this error message has: you should use a `FutureBuilder` if you want to render a `Future` value: https://www.google.com/search?q=The+argument+type+%27Future%27+can%27t+be+assigned+to+the+parameter+type+%27String%27

Comment: I just commented where I tried. Only the getmetadata method is returning a Future, does that mean I should add another FutureBuilder under the current one

Comment: Yup. Whenever you want to display a future value in your UI, you will either need a `FutureBuilder` or some other way to handle the asynchronous nature of the data. If you don't know how to do the latter yet, a `FutureBuilder` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Ill be trying this out immediately

Comment: I appreciate your assistance

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. I just needed to use a `FutureBuilder`. Could your post your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  --- I linked your question to a few others about the topic, since that is the solution that others should also apply when they land here.